# Issue with GcpProjectIdProvider on adding spring-cloud-gcp-starter-bigquery to Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-bigquery

Hi I am trying to add spring-cloud-gcp-starter-bigquery to my project. He is my code

Added these lines to pox.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-bigquery</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

On running, I get the following error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.bigquery.GcpBigQueryAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.spring.core.GcpProjectIdProvider' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.spring.core.GcpProjectIdProvider' in your configuration.
```

I didn't add any single line of code just included spring-cloud-gcp-starter-bigquery in my pom.xml. I have checked that lib appeared in my dependencies and saw that GcpProjectIdProvider file exists.

Comment: Try the following please: ```<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-bigquery</artifactId>
</dependency>```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I was migrating to SpringBoot 3

The issue was that one of the dependencies had a Google Storage Implementation class with the annotation

```
@Import(GcpStorageAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Removing the above did the trick for me.

Didn't face this issue with SpringBoot2 through the code was same.